# Find the parabola given two endpoints and the midpoint along the curve

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

It has arbitrary orientation in 2D.

[image: parabola from endpoints and midpoint]

I thought to equate the formulas for the arc lengths (s) between the midpoint and each end point from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Length_of_an_arc_of_a_parabola  :

$$
h={p \over 2}
$$

$$
q = \sqrt {f^2+h^2}
$$

$$
s = {{hq}\over f} + f \space ln{({{h+q} \over f})}
$$

where
$p$ is the perpendicular distance from the point to the axis of symmetry and
$f$ is the focal length. This leaves an equation with 3 unknowns - $p$ for each point and $f$. I hope to find other formulas involving those same variables to lock it down.

EDIT: I've realized that I don't need to solve this problem after all. It seems to have come from some sloppy documentation. It was supposed to be the midpoint in a special coordinate system used to describe it parametrically, which turns out to be quite easy.